# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ice Cream' error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to show stock records of a particular product. While passing id of that product to stock records, it is showing invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ice Cream' error.
My code looks like this:
models.py

```
class mProduct(models.Model):


 mProduct_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 mProduct_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 mProduct_qtyunit = 
 models.ForeignKey(mProductUnit,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Product 
                  ##Unit has one to many relationship with 
                        ##mProduct
 mProduct_qty=models.FloatField(default=0) ##current stock



 def __str__(self):
     return self.mProduct_name

class mStock(models.Model):
  mStock_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  mStock_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  mStock_product=models.ForeignKey(mProduct,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  mStock_qty=models.FloatField()
```

views.py
In this view, I am trying to get object for a particular product and use it to get it's stock records through filter().

```
def mStockDetailView(request,id):
    model=mStock
    m=get_object_or_404(mProduct,mProduct_id=id)

    stock=mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m.mProduct_name)
    context={
       'stock':stock,
    }

    return render(request,'dairyapp/stock-details.html',context)
```

template: productlist.html
I passed product id as parameter with url.

```
{% for p in product %}
<a href="{% url 'dairyapp:stock-detail' id=p.mProduct_id %}">
 {{p.mProduct_name}}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

urls.py

```
 path('stockrecords/<id>',views.mStockDetailView,name='stock-detail'),
```

Despite this, I am getting
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ice Cream' error

Can anyone provide solution for this error?

Traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/stockrecords/5

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dairyapp.apps.DairyappConfig',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/media/coder/Multimedia/My Projects/Software/Dairy/Dairy Soft/dairy/dairyapp/views.py" in mStockDetailView
  79.     stock=mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m.mProduct_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1225.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1096.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  20.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  115.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  965.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /stockrecords/5
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ice Cream'
```

Comment: Please post the full exception traceback. That will help us to answer your question.

Comment: You should post a full traceback. Anyways, the message says some place somewhere where a number was expected (some line of code is trying to typecast to int) is being passed 'Ice Cream'. So check your data as well.

Comment: I would guess it is on this line: `stock=mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m.mProduct_name)`. Perhaps `m.mProduct_name` should be `m.mProduct_id`.

Comment: 'Ice Cream' error- one of my favourite tracebacks

Comment: mProduct is a foreign key for mStock. I think `m.mProduct_id` can't be used to get mStock objects. The problem might be with `mStock_product=m.mProduct_name`. But I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Looks like your traceback isn't from the code you posted (the traceback shows an `mStock.objects.get` while the code shows an `mStock.objects.filter`). Please update one or the other so that they agree.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @FamousJameous Traceback has now been updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the traceback I am quite certain the problem is on this line:

```
stock=mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m.mProduct_name)
```

You are attempting to get an mStock object by filtering on the foreign key that points to an mProduct object. You are using the keyword argument `mStock_product` so the value passed should refer to an mProduct. You are passing `m.mProduct_name` which is a string. Instead you should pass `m.mProduct_id` which is your reference to an mProject object. So, the new line should be:

```
stock = mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m.mProduct_id)
```

or you can let Django figure out the primary key and just pass the object like this (Thanks to A.L.Flanagan for pointing this out):

```
stock = mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m)
```

Comment: I believe this will also work: `stock=mStock.objects.filter(mStock_product=m)`. Django "knows" what the foreign key is, so you don't have to tell it.

Comment: @A.L.Flanagan Yes, I think you are right. I couldn't remember if that was valid or not and I couldn't find it in the docs and I was too lazy to try it. I'll add that as an option though, thanks.